# Loading image into enclave memory

Tags: windows, visual-c++, msdn, enclave

I'm trying to use the new windows 1709 feature that allows to load a DLL into enclave memory.

I didn't find *ANY* documentation or example of doing it. 
As far as I understand these are the steps to achieve it:

1. Check that VBS (only VBS supports enclave image) enclave type is supported using [`IsEnclaveTypeSupported`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/mt592870(v=vs.85).aspx).
2. Use [`CreateEnclave`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/mt592866(v=vs.85).aspx) function to create enclave.
3. Use [`LoadEnclaveImage`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/mt844248(v=vs.85).aspx) function to load the image into the enclave memory.

Here is code snippet that I tried to use:

```
HANDLE h = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, GetCurrentProcessPid());
BOOL vbsSupport = IsEnclaveTypeSupported(ENCLAVE_TYPE_VBS); //returns TRUE
ENCLAVE_CREATE_INFO_VBS vci = { 0 };
vci.Flags = 1;
LPVOID lpAddress = CreateEnclave(h, NULL, 0x10000, NULL, ENCLAVE_TYPE_VBS, &vci, sizeof(ENCLAVE_CREATE_INFO_VBS), NULL);
```

The call the `CreateEnclave` return `NULL` and set the last error code to 0x32 (The request is not supported).

Any ideas how to make it work ?

Comment: After further investigation I noticed something very weird.
When compiling the above code in 64bit, the call to createEnclave never returns. Furthermore, the computer is stuck, and closing the application isn't possible even with Process Hacker or Procexp. It seems that the kthread is stuck in a deadlock. I tried the following with more than 4 different fully updated computers (even without VBS/SGX ever been enabled).

Answer (score 0):

Is Hyper-V enabled?
It's required for enclaves to work.

Comment: Sure it is.
Before enabling it IsEnclaveTypeSupported returned FALSE.
After enabling hyper-v and secure boot, IsEnclaveTypeSupported return TRUE.

Comment: My try works, but I cannot find the LoadEnclaveImage function into the dlls.

Comment: You have to update to the latest Windows SDK to find these functions

Comment: Check vertdll.dll exports and you will see that the function is not there. Basically I can't even find api-ms-win-core-enclave-l1-1-0.dll. 

Regarding your question, the 0x10000 size might be wrong (I tried with 1MB and it works).

Comment: I found it in kernelbase.dll. But it won't load a dll file, it says that it's not signed (even if I sign it).